# Php Looping $a = new ShipPackage('UPS');

Tags: php

I need a PHP loop for the following code below: What is the easiest way to produce the below example.

```
$a = new ShipPackage('UPS');
$a->setParameter('length','5');
$a->setParameter('width','5');
$a->setParameter('height','5');
$a->setParameter('weight','5');

$combined->addPackageToShipment($a);
```

**If loop 3X, it should look like this below:**

```
$a = new ShipPackage('UPS');
$a->setParameter('length','5');
$a->setParameter('width','5');
$a->setParameter('height','5');
$a->setParameter('weight','5');
$combined->addPackageToShipment($a);

$a2 = new ShipPackage('UPS');
$a2->setParameter('length','5');
$a2->setParameter('width','5');
$a2->setParameter('height','5');
$a2->setParameter('weight','5');
$combined->addPackageToShipment($a2);

$a3 = new ShipPackage('UPS');
$a3->setParameter('length','5');
$a3->setParameter('width','5');
$a3->setParameter('height','5');
$a3->setParameter('weight','5');
$combined->addPackageToShipment($a3);
```

Comment: It seems like you should have put a little more effort into this question, or at least looking for the answer elsewhere first.

Comment: Jimmy Sawmaster is correct. Make with your failed attempts.

Comment: you have to be thor·ough   with language basics such as loop,datatypes etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
for($x = 0; $x < 3;$x++)
{
  $a = new ShipPackage('UPS');
  $a->setParameter('length','5');
  $a->setParameter('width','5');
  $a->setParameter('height','5');
  $a->setParameter('weight','5');

  $combined->addPackageToShipment($a);
}
```

Im not sure about your question but as how i understand it, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to loop through the code as many times as necessary. You did not give any info about why you need the loop, so I would assume a `for` loop will be best.

```
for ($b = 0; $b < 3; $b++) {

    $a = new ShipPackage('UPS');
    $a->setParameter('length','5');
    $a->setParameter('width','5');
    $a->setParameter('height','5');
    $a->setParameter('weight','5');

    $combined->addPackageToShipment($a);

}
```

Change `3` (in `$b < 3`) to the number of times you want to loop. You can replace `3` with a variable, if applicable.

You can also use a `while` loop to execute code *while* a certain condition is true.

```
while ($canShip) {

    $a = new ShipPackage('UPS');
    $a->setParameter('length','5');
    $a->setParameter('width','5');
    $a->setParameter('height','5');
    $a->setParameter('weight','5');

    $combined->addPackageToShipment($a);

}
```